# How many volumes of the light novels did Durarara season 1 cover?

Tags: durarara

How many volumes of the light novels did Durarara season 1 utilize? Where should I start reading if I want to continue from after the first season ended? (I know the second season is already being broadcasted). Also, are the light novels still on-going or are they finished?

Comment: The initial run of light novels (13 volumes) finished in early 2014, but a sequel series started up a few months ago (titled "Durarara!! SH"), and has two volumes out so far and is ongoing. Dunno where the first season of the anime ends, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durarara!!#Light_novel) and [Manga Updates](http://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=49306) say that the anime covers the first three volumes of the light novels.

**From Manga Updates:**

> **Status in Country of Origin**
> 13 Volumes (Complete)
>
> **Anime Start/End Chapter**
> Starts at volume 1
> Ends at volume 3

*(As per senshin's comment, a sequel light novel series titled [Durarara!! SH](http://durarara.wikia.com/wiki/Durarara!!_SH) is underway and has 2 volumes published at the time of writing)*

**Wikipedia excerpt about the [anime adaptation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durarara!!#Anime):**

> An anime adaption of the light novels was announced in the wraparound sleeve of the sixth volume of the light novel. The anime is produced by Brain's Base and started airing on January 7, 2010 on MBS, TBS, and CBC. Crunchyroll simulcasted the anime at 480p and 720p within 24 hours of its Japanese premiere. Other users were able see the same episode in standard definition for free one week later. **The anime adapted the first three novels,** and it was licensed by Beez Entertainment for European release, while at Anime Expo 2010, Aniplex of America confirmed that they have the license to Durarara!!, later producing an English dub for a January 2011 release. The English dub was produced at Bang Zoom! Entertainment. The music for the first season was composed by Makoto Yoshimori, who also wrote the music for Baccano!.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I'd highly suggest you read the light novels translations if you can (even the ones that take place during the time of the anime). There a lot of stuff not even mentioned in the anime. A lot of the events are either cut out, shortened, or completely adverted into something similar, and all out to nearly bashing Izaya's character. It makes him out to a whole lot worse than what he really is. Preferably in Volume 9 for his case.

Comment: This is fine advice, but it does not actually answer OP's question.